# ERRORLEVEL -1073741795

Tags: assembly, nasm

```
section .data
    var: db 'Hello World', 10

section .text
    _start:
        mov rax, 1
        mov rdi, 1
        mov rsi, var
        mov rdx, 11
        syscall

        mov rax, 60
        xor rdi, rdi

        syscall
```

it says: programm has stopped

error level: -1073741795

i use compiler NASM: NASM version 2.16.01 compiled on Dec 21 2022

i use linker: GNU ld (GNU Binutils) 2.41
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This program is free software; you may redistribute it under the terms of
the GNU General Public License version 3 or (at your option) a later version.
This program has absolutely no warranty.

CPU: intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3770 CPU

OS: Windows 10 pro

what i write to compile or link:

compiler: %nasm% -f win64 path-to-file.asm -o path-to-file.o

linker: %ld% path-to-file.o -o path-to-file.exe

i have downloaded nasm compiler and linker ld from msys2.

Comment: On what OS?  What commands did you run to build this code into an executable?  It should work on x86-64 Linux with `nasm -felf64 foo.asm` ; `ld -o foo  foo.o`, but that doesn't look like a Linux error message.

Comment: i use windows 10 pro

Comment: `1` and `60` aren't Windows write or exit system-call numbers.  According to https://j00ru.vexillium.org/syscalls/nt/64/ , on most versions of the Win10 kernel, RAX=0x0001 / `syscall` is `NtWorkerFactoryWorkerReady`.  And `60` (0x003c) is `NtDuplicateObject`

Comment: The only way this code can work on Windows is inside WSL, or inside a VM.  It's using the Linux system-call ABI; native Windows programs have their system calls handled as Windows.

Comment: `-1073741795` is `STATUS_INVALID_INSTRUCTION`. Compiling with `win64` is wrong, this is Linux code, not Windows code. You need to compile it for Linux and then run it in Linux (e.g. in WSL). Or, change your code to use the Windows API.